# Android N Fileprovider to /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: java, android

Since Android API24 i must work with Fileprovider to open a PDF file.
the File ist stored in /storage/emulated/0/TestApp/

java code

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TestApp/" + pdf);
        //Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        System.out.println(file.toString());
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Belege.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

        System.out.println(path.toString());
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent intent1 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open With");
            startActivity(intent1);

        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Application Available to fiew this file type",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

and the path.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="AppWare" path="/storage/emulated/0/"/>
```

by this i get this error :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/TestApp/0NA17200010.pdf

the file is in this dir.

That can i do ?

Comment: Change to  `path="."`.

Comment: You have three calls to setFlags(). That will not work. Only the last one will survive. Just set them all at the same time OR'ed.

Comment: Big Thanks ! It works